# Error after running apps script by trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have code below. I've created trigger for this function. Type of trigger by minutes - every 15 minutes. "A" cell is a number that should be copy to G column by trigger. When it runs as result I see #ERROR. I need help with this

Maybe this #ERROR shows after running Delete function? And something wrong with this function?

```
function hourChart() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PvD (auto)");
  var value = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var range = sheet.getRange("G1:G").getValues();
  var lastRow = null;
  var i = 0;
  while(i < range.length) {
    if (range[i][0] !== "") {
      i++
    } else {
      lastRow = i +1;
      break;
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(`G${lastRow}`).setValue(value)
}
function hourChartDelete() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PvD (auto)");
  var range = sheet.getRange("G2:G");
  range.clear();
}
```

Please look to file

[image]

Comment: Please add more details... type of trigger, sample data of A1 and G1:G and the expected results.

Comment: I thought it was something about the way the range string was constructed `G${lastRow}` but I'm unable to reproduce your error.

Comment: @TheWizEd Maybe something wrong in additional function that I input?

Comment: Which is it `PvD (auto)` or `PvD (Auto)`?

Comment: @TheWizEd its same sheet

Comment: No, they are spelled different case.

Comment: @TheWizEd Thanks. I missed it. Maybe that's why it is not work correctly.

Comment: @TheWizEd Not this mistake. Still work incorrect.

Comment: Is `var value = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();` the result of a formula?  It produces an #ERROR so you are copying that string?

Comment: @TheWizEd Yes. It's wrong?